# Calculate execution time in callback functions nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need to calculate execution time in callback functions?

**Use case**

In my nodejs application there is a REST API endpoint that responsible for read a file and write into the db. this process should happened in server background user is not waiting for respond. Process like make API request -> start process -> respond to user notifying process started. I'm not using await, all are handle by callbacks. Please find below pseudo code get some idea.

```
function callbackRetry(error, data) {
  if(data.hasFailedItems) {
     saveDataToDb(data.failedItems)
  }
}

function saveDataToDb(params) {
  dbSdkSaveData(params, (error, data) => callbackRetry(error, data))
}

router.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
  forEach( reading file line by line ) {
     const params = line;
     saveDataToDb(params)
  }
  
  res.json({message : 'process successfully executed!'})
}
```

I just want calculate how much time consumed to complete these db saving and retrying operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [performance](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html#perf_hooks_class_performance) module. Play around with the logging positions to get desired results

```
const { performance } = require('perf_hooks');

function callbackRetry(error, data){
  if(data.hasFailedItems){
     saveDataToDb(data.failedItems)
  }
}

function saveDataToDb(params){
  dbSdkSaveData(params, (error, data) => callbackRetry(error, data))
}

router.get('/',(req, res, next) => {
  const t0 = performance.now()
  forEach( reading file line by line ) {
     const params = line;
     saveDataToDb(params)
  }
  const t1 = performance.now()
  console.log("Execution time:" + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
  res.json({message : 'process successfully executed!'})
}
```